# config flask app with a app.config.from_object

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app with MySQL DB i want to config my app with `config.formobject(object)`
Then, I write the following class:

```
import os

    class Config:
        DEBUG = True
        TESTING = False
        SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://root:tool789@localhost/city'"
        SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
        SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(24)
        MAIL_SERVER = "Yourdomain"
        MAIL_USERNAME = "username"
        MAIL_PASSWORD = "password"
        MAIL_PORT = 456
        MAIL_USE_SSL = True
        MAIL_USE_TSL = False
```

and import it to my `_init_.py` here :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from app.config import *
app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config.from_object(Config)

from app import views
from app import admin_views
from app.dbmodels import *

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

when I run my server, I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\websiteproject\run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\websiteproject\app\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\websiteproject\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 219, in __init__
     self.init_app(app)
   File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\websiteproject\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 307, in init_app
     raise RuntimeError(
 RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set.
```

what is my problem and who can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your `db` client using the `app`'s configuration, but you haven't configured `app` yet. Try configuring app first:

```
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Comment: M thank u i fix that but now i face another error sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1049, "Unknown database 'city''")

Comment: @PouryaMohamadi your `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` var is pointing to a local mysql DB, which should contain a DB named `city` - but according to your error, it doesn't.

Comment: M thank you i copy that name from another file i that was a " in the name + thae correct name